# highcharts data values from different variable or from different file

Tags: highcharts

```
var series = [{
            type: 'area',
            name: '',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 100,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
            data: [a,b,c]
}
];
```

here i want the a,b,c from different variable or different file. how can i get it

Comment: It seems like you haven't tried to google same before asking question. Have a look at this. http://www.knowstack.com/different-ways-of-loading-highcharts-data/ OR this http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ayycv/

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific.  You can accomplish that in many different ways, but it depends on what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

create an array and push your data iterating every response like below :

```
var data = [];
data.push[a]; 
data.push[b];
```

use this data variable in your series.